# Arduino won't allow to upload more than once

Tags: arduino, atmega

I have an Uno-based Arduino (Robocore Blackboard) which has an ATMEGA328P-PU onboard. It's showing a strange behaviour: I can upload any code once, but if I try to upload anything else (or even the same code) after that, it says, `vrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding`. The only way to re-upload without error is unplugging and plugging the USB cable.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

PS: it is being powered by USB, no external power supply.

Comment: I found a possible solution in http://3dwest.blogspot.de/2013/12/arduino-in-osx-109-stk500recv.html

It seems to work here o/

Answer (score 0):

Arduino cards have auto-reset feature. When you load fresh code from IDE ,arduino automatically reboot for uploading new code. Maybe your card don't support it. So, you can try push the reset button on the board before starting upload your code.